# Smack reading old events

Tags: java, openfire, smack

I am having a problem with an application using Smack 3.1 and a server running openfire. Upon starting the application, it will read the last message on the node. This doesn't work since the messages are parsed, processed and placed into a db. Besides sending a message creation time in the payload, is there any way to stop this duplication? (Actually if there is anyway to signal that a message has been "consumed" would be fantastic)

Comment: What type of message/node are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to pubsub then you can either configure the node so that it does not persist items with `persist_items` and `max_items`.

If you have no control over the node creation then what you can do is check for the delay namespace (`jabber:x:delay` and/or `urn:xmpp:delay`) in the packet

```
public void processPacket(Packet pkt) {
   DelayInformation delay = (DelayInformation)pkg.getExtension("x", "jabber:x:delay");
   if (delay != null)
      return; //Discard this packet
   delay = (DelayInformation)pkg.getExtension("x", "urn:xmpp:delay");
   if (delay != null)
      return; //Discard this as well
   //Otherwise this is a good packet
   ...
}
```

You can also make some decision by examining the `DelayInformation` object as to how long, reason, etc.

If it is PEP then you will always get the last item published and I think there is no way of determining if it was delayed viz. there is no delay info in the packet.

You need to either get [nightly builds](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/nightly_smack.jsp) or [build your own](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp) for pubsub support. I don't think the current version Smack 3.1.0 supoorts pubsub.

Comment: When you said pubsub it sparked my memories and a quick browse through the maven dependencies reveals that we are using smackx-pubsub .4. I am still poking about but you have gotten me a world closer (and if this works out, an accepted answer)